# messages not getting added when using socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to design a chat application using sockets in react. Whenever a `new_message` event is triggered from backend, I'm trying to append that message in the exisiting messages array, but seems like that ain't working.
Here's the code what I tried:

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new_message", (data) => {                 // receving the event and appending the new message in the existing array of messages. 
      setConversation([...conversation, data.message]);
    });
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.emit("join_room", lead._id);
    if (lead._id !== undefined) {
      getConversationByRoomId(lead._id).then(({ data }) =>
        setConversation(data.conversation)
      );
    }
  }, [lead]);

  const handleKeyPress = async (e) => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      await postMessage(lead._id, { messageText: message });     // API which will save this message in the database and triggers an event called new_message to the socket
      setMessage("");
    }
  };
```

Somehow, it's only adding the new message in the conversation array and removes all the other conversation. What can be done to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the info you have given in your question, I think the first to change and observe would be the way `socket.on` is implemented. I wouldn't  bind a new event handler every time a state update happens and that too without removing the previous one in a cleanup function.

Try doing it the following way by taking advantage of **state updator** function :-

```
useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("new_message", (data) => {                
      setConversation(prevConversation=>[...prevConversation, data.message]);
    });
  },[]);
```

Also make sure that `getConversationByRoomId` is actually returning the whole `conversation` array as you intend to by logging it's value before setting the same in state.